# Is it possible to stop community user from modifying drupal 6 questions?

Tags: discussion, community-user, question-lists

Community user usually modifies old questions so they will shown in high positions of active question list. But nowadays drupal 6 is not supported any more and these questions doesn't gain more attentions.

I think it would be great if there were be a policy to stop questions with tag drupal 6 from being modified by community user.

Comment: Something similar: [Should Drupal 5 posts be closed?](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3530/1908)

Comment: Some people still using Drupal 6 and you can't stop them using it. It takes time to migrate. Drupal 6 questions are still on-topic here I guess, nobody prevents you from asking them.

Comment: Will answer when I have time, but see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions

Comment: @kenorb I don't mean to close these questions, I just ask to prevent community user from modifying them and pull these questions up to top of the active question list

Comment: That's why I rarely go to the active tab, I mostly hangout in the [newest tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ArIiC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Bumping old questions without accepted answers is not done just for making users answer them (even if that is still possible and acceptable). Bumping those questions is also done to moderate them.

When users see a bumped question, independently from the Drupal version for which the question is asked, and independently from the user who caused the question to be bumped, they could:

- Check if there is any spam answer
- Check if there are comments written as answers
- Check if they know the answer and they are able to write one
- Check if the question is on-topic or it can be closed for any of the closing reasons we have today
- Check if the question has been already asked, and the other question has answers; in this case, the bumped question could be closed as duplicate

Some of the points I listed are valid even if the question was bumped from the Community user. The fact the question is about Drupal 6, and it is an old question, doesn't make the question unanswerable, nor exempted from moderation.

See also the answers given on [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions), which explain the purpose of bumping questions, and when it is done.

> Random bumping is not done just to get old unanswered questions answered. It is also done to highlight questions that need other kinds of attention, like being closed.
>   — [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99673/140449)

> I recently tweaked the community bumping so that it **favors unanswered questions with lots of views**. Right now it takes the top 100 unanswered questions with no recent activity *by views*, then picks randomly from within that group.
>   — [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690/140449)